# readdir ignores non-empty repositories beginning with a dot

Tags: c, linux

I'm writing a dotfile repository manager, but the command to delete a repository doesn't work. 
It goes to the repository folder, then it must list all files and directories so that I'll be able to delete them. trouble is, it lists every file or directory I'll need to remove, but it excludes `.git`, which is non-empty. I did further tests with other repositories, and my conclusion is that every non-empty directory whose name begins with a dot is ignored, whereas "normal" dotfiles are okay.
Here's the offending code, which I'll describe quickly.

rm_dotfiles_repository is called with the name of the repository, `repo_dir(repo)` gets to the repository and then the `readdir` loop is launched. I need to recursively remove folders, that's why I filter between folders and plain old files. Note that i don't exclude the folders `.` and `..`, but i'll add that soon.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#include "repository.h"
#include "helpers.h"
#include "nftwcallbacks.h"

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <error.h>
void rm_dotfiles_repository(char* repo)
{
    repo_dir(repo);
    /* Remove the repository's files recursively
     * TODO: Remove the symbolic links in ~ before removing the repo
     * We remove the repository, target by target */
    DIR* dir = NULL;
    struct dirent* file = NULL;
    struct stat stat_data;
    dir = opendir(".");
    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    file = readdir(dir);
    while ((file = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(file->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(file->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            /* TODO: why isn't .git listed, even if .gitmodules is listed ? After tests, it seems that .something repositories which are non-empty 
             * aren't listed*/
            if(stat(file->d_name, &stat_data))
            {
                perror("Error");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (S_ISDIR(stat_data.st_mode))
            {
                remove_target(repo, file->d_name);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Remove file %s\n", file->d_name);
            }
        }
    }
    if (closedir(dir))
    {
        perror("Error:");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void install_target(char* repo, char* target)
{
    repo_dir(repo);
    if (nftw(target, install, 4, 0))
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
} 

void remove_target(char* repo, char* target)
{
    printf("Remove target %s from repo %s\n", target, repo);
}
```

Could you help me find the cause of the problem ? Thanks in advance

EDIT: As Mats Petersson asked, [here](https://gist.github.com/mrabault/e717a32d201001fe9b18)'s the complete code, the snippet I've given is repository.c

Comment: Any chance you could write a complete standalone example, rather than a snippet with a lot of include files that aren't standard. It should have a "main" for example.

Comment: I have a standalone example, yes, but there's lots of code. I'll do a gist though.

Comment: Well, I just removed the "I don't need it" bits of your code, created a directory called `.git` and ran your code, and it says, somewhere in the middle of "removing" all other files, "Remove target .git from repo". So the only two possible scenarios is that you don't have read-rights of the `.git` directory, or there is some difference between your system and mine....

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have the `drwxr-xr-x` rights, and I'm the owner. Weird. I'm on Arch Linux with all packages up to date.

Comment: My box is a 64-bit Fedora. If you run your code in an otherwise empty directory with just a ".git" directory, does it work?

Comment: It doesn't work, it doesn't output anything.

Comment: Very strange. I'd run `strace` on it in that case, and see if there's any function returning something unusual.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31030/discussion-between-matthr3d-and-mats-petersson)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code "skips" the first entry in a directory:

```
file = readdir(dir);
while ((file = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
```

Remove the

```
file = readdir(dir);
```

and all will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your patience, Mats. The error was indeed between the keyboard and the chair ... PEBKAC